# SSIS Formatting input from flat file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, text-parsing

I'm a SSIS newbie. I wanna format the inputs of my flat file before saving the entries in a database table. Initially I created a flat file as follows:-

- "1","Superman","Metropolis"
- "2","Batman","Gotham"
- "3","Spiderman","New York"
- "4","James Bond","London"
- "5","Green Lantern","Oa"

  The solution for stripping this was simple as shown here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1316/strip-double-quotes-from-an-import-file-in-integration-services-ssis/

  But now i have created a new similar package and given my input file like this:-

  - "6", "TMNT", "Sewers NY"
  - "7", "Iron Man", "New York"

Note here I've put a space after the delimiting comma.  Now when I follow the above method the first number field stripped of the double quotes, but rest of the entries retain their quotes. Any idea how to work around this? One suggestion on a similar question on stackoverflow mentioned use of a "Transformation script". Since I'm a newbie can anyone please throw light on this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Script component transformation. Select all columns, and change them to ReadWrite. The code:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.ID = Row.ID.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    Row.Movie = Row.Movie.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    Row.City = Row.City.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
}
```

If you want to trim the spaces you can use

```
Row.ID.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
```

You would also need to take care if you want to preserve the values that are "  ". Please post if the suggestion was helpful or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanx Anoop ! Will definitely try this

Answer (score 0):

In the 'General' tab you can set a text qualifier of ". Then those quotes will be ignored.

Then you don't need to write error prone script when there is a simple solution.

Comment: Please read the question properly. I know of this method and it works in the first case. It does not work in my second case!